# Scroll bar pages conflicting with banner elements positioning

Tags: html, css, position, scrollbar, navbar

I was wondering how I could stop these elements from moving when I navigate to a page with a scroll bar. I've noticed that my elements move slightly if I select a page with a scroll bar. [Here](http://gyazo.com/22b3f73f3982d119fa645eebf89b9b8c) is what I mean. I was thinking of somehow forcing a scroll bar to appear on all my pages but I'm not even sure how to do that and I'd rather see if there is a different solution first. If anyone could help me I'd appreciate it. If there's any more code you need let me know and I can add that to the question.

Thanks, Grant

Here is my CSS for the banner/header and nav bar

```
/*TOP BANNER SECTION*/

#banner {
height: 100px;
    position: relative;}

#logo {position:relative;
top: -90px;
left:700px;}

#ip_box {
         width:210px;
         height:43px;
         background:#212121;                 
         color: white;
         font-size: 15px;
         bottom: 10px;
         left: 77px;
         position: absolute;}

#ip_text {bottom: 11px;
          left: 64px;        
          color: white;
          position:absolute;}

#teamspeak_box {width:159px;
                height:43px;
                background:#212121;
                bottom: 10px;
                right: 76px;
                position: absolute;}

#teamspeak_box_2 {width:43px;
                  height:43px;
                  background:#313131;
                  bottom: 10px;
                  right: 191px;
                  position:absolute;}

#teamspeak_text {color: white;
                 bottom: 21px;
                 right: 66px;
                 position: absolute;}          

#teamspeak_image {bottom: 9px;
                 right: 104px;
                position: absolute;}

#red_bar {border-bottom: 5px solid #C62828;
bottom: 190px;
position:relative;}

/*TOP NAV BAR SECTION*/

* {margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;}

#nav_bar {background-color: #313131;
          height: 45px;
          text-align: center;
          position:relative;}

#nav_bar ul {padding: 0;}

#nav_bar > ul > li {display: inline-block;}

#nav_bar ul > li > a {color: white;
                      display: block;
                      text-decoration: none;
                      font-weight: normal;
                      padding-left: 15px;
                      padding-right: 15px;
                      line-height: 45px;
                      transition: all 0.5s ease;}

#nav_bar ul li ul {display: none;
                   list-style: none;
                   position: absolute;
                   background: white;
                   margin-left:0px;
                   box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px;
                   text-align: left;
                   z-index:1;}

#nav_bar ul li a.active-page {background-color: #212121;}

#nav_bar ul li:hover ul li a {line-height: 2em;}

#nav_bar ul li a:hover {background: #212121;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#nav_bar ul li:hover ul {display: block;}

#nav_bar ul li ul li a {color: #000000;
                        display: block;}

#nav_bar ul li ul li a:hover {background: #1565C0;
                              color: white;
transition: all 0.5s ease;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `overflow-y: scroll` to the body element, this will force the scroll bar to always display.

Comment: Fantastic thanks! Is that the only way would you say?

Comment: I cannot think of anything else really, not without working out which pages don't have a scroll bar and then "pushing it left" to match the other pages

Answer (score 0):

If you have a container try setting the width of your content to 100% because the content needs to adjust to compensate for adding in and removing the scrollbar. The content looks correct with the scrollbar but when it is removed it is just centering itself within the page to compensate for the extra room and doesn't change size so it appears smaller.